# why list(print(x.upper(), end=' ') for x in 'spam') gets a [None, None, None, None] list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

On page 608 of 《Learning Python 5th》 ,there is a example code:

```
>>> list(print(x.upper(), end=' ') for x in 'spam')
S P A M [None, None, None, None]
```

so,why [None, None, None, None] pops up on the last?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `print` function returns `None`... Your expression therefore constructs a list `[None, None, None, None]`.  Since you are in the python Read Evaluate Print Loop (REPL), the result of the expression gets printed after it is evaluated...

So, the evaluation of the expression has the side-effect of printing `S P A M` and then after the the expression is evaluated, it's value gets printed (`[None, None, None, None]`).